# Qt 4.8.1 and Visual Studio 2010 compiler loses floating point precision

Tags: c++, qt

I'm writing some kind of financial app both for Windows and Linux. My app is written with Qt. For compilation on Windows x86 i use Visual Studio 2010 compiler on Windows 7. All operations with money amounts performed in integers, all amounts presented in cents (amount * 100). When my computations completed, i need to convert cents in dollars back (by dividing cents by 100).
My problem in strange precision lose. E.g. I have 1222202 amount in cents. Tax for operation is 9%, so, tax value will be 1099.98 or 109998 in cents, and result amount 11122.02 (1112202 in cents). My problem is precision lose when i try to convert amount from cents to dollars, 02 cents always lost, and amount is 11122. I tried different ways of conversions, result value always truncated.

Example:

```
float divider = 100.0f;
float floatAmount = 1222202;
float outAmount - floatAmount / divider;
```

or:

```
float divider = 100.00f;
float floatAmount = accountedAmount; // 1222202
char buffer[16];
sprintf(buffer, "%.2f", floatAmount/divider);
float outAmount = atof(buffer);
```

outAmount always 12222, but buffer is 12222.02 in string representation.

Comment: Try using double instead of float.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Any reason you are not using QString::toDouble(), when you use Qt anyway?

Answer (score 0):

The idea of using cents instead of dollars is so you can use an integer type. The comment suggesting to use `double` fails to understand that.

You can then calculate `int dollars = amount / 100` and `int cents = amount % 100`

Answer (score 0):

You've not specified how you check the value of `outAmount`. I'll assume you used `std::cout` or another `ostream` object.

Default precision of `ostream` streams is 6 decimal places. This will round your number to 12222. See this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "12222.02 default 6 dec places:\t" << 12222.02f << endl;
    cout << "12222.02 with 7 dec places:\t" << setprecision(7) << 12222.02f << endl;
    cout << "12222.02 with 15 dec places:\t" << setprecision(15) << 12222.02f << endl;
}
```

The output is:

```
12222.02 default 6 dec places:  12222
12222.02 with 7 dec places:     12222.02
12222.02 with 15 dec places:    12222.01953125
```

Also note that you really should switch to `double` instead of `float` because such large numbers can't be really well represented with 24-bit mantissa of `float`: multiply your amount by 10 and you'll have an error of cent if truncated to integer - all this will affect computation precision because of round-offs in intermediate calculations.